# Dimension of degree $2$ morphisms $\mathbb P^1 \to \mathbb P^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-space

I am reading [this introduction paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.1260.pdf) on Gromov-Witten theory, and on page 5, in second paragraph he says:

> Within this locus of maps, there is a sublocus consisting of those maps
>   which map as $2 : 1$ covers of a line in $\mathbb P^2$
>   . This is a $4$-dimensional locus, since
>   we need two parameters to describe the target line, and two to describe
>   the ramification points of the map.

I am a little confused about this. I suppose that two maps $\mathbb P^1 \to \mathbb P^2$ are equivalent if there is an automorphism $\mathbb P^1 \to \mathbb P^1$ making the diagram commutative, and he is computing the dimension of the equivalence classes. Therefore, a $2:1$ cover $\mathbb P^1 \to \mathbb P^1$ will be determined only by the branched value, hence is described by one parameter. Why he says two?

Comment: There are two branch points?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Let us call a point in the sourse "branch point" and a point in the target "branch value". Then, I suppose there is only one branch point and one branch value. Besides, I think it has nothing to do with the branch points as we can use an automorphism of $\mathbb P^1$ to make it no difference.

Comment: - There are two 'branch values' (these are usually called branch points - the 'branch point' you're suggesting are usually called ramification points). You can see this using Riemann-Hurwitz, but maybe concretely with an example such as $\mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ given by $z\mapsto z^2$. Your branch points are $0$ and $\infty$. 

- You are only modding out by automorphisms of the domain $\mathbb{P}^1$ and not the target, so it does make a difference.

Comment: Another way to see the claim is that a 2:1 map $\mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ is given by two homogeneous polynomials $f,g$, and the map is given by $[x,y] \mapsto [f(x,y),g(x,y)]$. This space is 5-dimensional (a degree two homogeneous polynomial has three parameters, and you want to mod out by scaling (-1 dimension)). Now mod out by $Aut(\mathbb{P}^1)$ which is 3-dimensional.

Comment: @loch Thank you for your detailed explanation! I am so stupid...

Comment: @loch And you can post it as an answer if you want. I will accept it.